# Using RealmSwift and SwiftUI, how can I look at a record in the view and change it simultaneously, without view poping out?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I'm getting an object from Realm using @ObservedResults and then I need to modify the record in the same screen. Like adding items and deleting items, but I need this to happen **without returning to previous NavigationView**. And I need to update the view displaying the data as its updated.

It seems that @StateRealmObject should be the solution, but how can I designate a stored Realm object as a StateRealmObject? What would be a better approach?

Model:

```
class Order: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @objc dynamic var orderID : String = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name : String = "No Name"
    let orderLineId = List<OrderLine>()
    .
    .
    .
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "orderID"
      }
    
}
```

View: (simplified)

```
struct OrderView: View {
    var currentOrder : Order?
    @ObservedResults (Order.self) var allOrders
    var realm = try! Realm()

    init(orderId: String) {
        currentOrder = allOrders.filter("orderID ==\"\(orderId)\"")[0].thaw()
    }

    func deleteOrderLine(id: String, sku: String) {
        
        try! realm.write {
            let query = allOrderLines.filter("id == \"\(id)\" AND productSku == \"\(sku)\"")[0]
            realm.delete(query)
            
        }
    }

var body: some View {
//Here is where all order data is displayed. When deleting a line. The view pops out. I //need to change data and keep view, and save changes as they are made. 
//If delete line func is called, it works, but it pops the view.
    
    deleteOrderLine(id: String, sku: String)

   }
}
```

As per request, this is the parent navigation view, which I believe is the core of the problem.

```
struct OrderListView2: View {
    @ObservedResults (Order.self) var allOrders

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
            ForEach(allOrders.sorted(byKeyPath: "dateCreated",ascending: false), id: \.self) { order in
    NavigationLink(destination: OrderView(orderId: order.orderID)){
    Text(order.info...)
    }

}
```

Comment: When using .onDelete(perform: deleteLine), it crashes with a "'RLMException', reason: 'Index 3 is out of bounds (must be less than 3).'" error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `allOrderLines` collection is not frozen.
This result set is live so when you delete an entry your SwiftUI view is displaying a result set that is older than your live collection.

Hence the `RLMException` for the index out of bounds. To solve this problem you must freeze that collection for the view then delete the desired object and then reload your frozen collection. To achieve this i would suggest you use a viewmodel.

```
class OrderViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var orders: Results<Order>
    
    init() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        self.orders = realm.objects(Order.self).freeze()
    }
    
    func deleteOrderLine(id: String, sku: String) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            let query = realm.objects(Order.self).filter("id == \"\(id)\" AND productSku == \"\(sku)\"")[0]
            realm.delete(query)
        }
        self.orders = realm.objects(Order.self).freeze()
    }
}
```

You can then use the `@Published` orders for your view. Initialize the viewmodel with `@StateObject var viewModel = OrderViewModel()`

Comment: Erwin, thanks for the answer, unfortunately after testing it, the view keeps on popping out to the previous navigation view.

Comment: Can you post the view code?

Comment: Ok, so I think I know why this is happening. Before accessing the Order, I have a List-ForEach NavigationView that lists all orders. Since I am making changes to the model, it seems the parent NavigationView gets reset and pops any child views. I figured a work around this, by casting the data and passing it to View, but if this is the only solution, I will have to rewrite a lot of code.